# Como centralizar menu dropdown no Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Por padrão, o menu do componente dropdown do Bootstrap 4 é alinhado à esquerda com o botão que o abre:

[image: Alinhamento padrão]

Preciso alinhar o menu do dropdown com o centro do botão, de modo que fique assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Encontrei a classe `dropdown-menu-right` que alinha à direita, mas não encontrei algo do tipo `dropdown-menu-center` para alinhar ao centro como na imagem acima.

Estou usando um dropdown básico do Bootstrap 4: https://codepen.io/tkrempser/pen/vwRjmK.

Comment: Adiciona o codigo do seu menu também para ficar mais facil te ajudar...

Comment: @Lodi Adicionei o código.

Comment: Se o botão estiver no canto esquerdo, ao centralizar o menu, este irá sair da tela por causa da largura. Você quer mover o botão pra direita?

Comment: @Sam Eu vou colocar o botão dentro de um container depois de centralizado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro vc tem que deixar o container do `dropdown` com o a largura do maior conteúdo. para isso criei uma classe *custom* e coloquei o `width` como `max-content`.

Depois vamos ajustar o `left` e o transforme original do `dropdown`. Ele por default já tem essas propriedades, mas para centralizar vc precisa ajusta-las, da forma que eu fiz, independente do tamanho do conteúdo ele sempre vai centralizar no botão.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Page Title</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
 <style>
  .drop-custom.show {
   width: max-content;
  }
  .drop-custom.show .dropdown-menu {
   left: 50% !important;
   transform: translate3d(-50%, 38px, 0px) !important;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>

 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-12">
    <div class="dropdown drop-custom">
     <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton"
      data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown button
     </button>
     <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here 12312312321</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```